# Include data from .js file into a link

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have prepared a worldmap with leaflet, with about 700 markers - it already works fine. Now I would like to make it possible to move to the points on the map via google maps. The relevant code part is this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < addressPoints.length; i++) {
            var a = addressPoints[i];
            var title = a[2];
            var name = a[3] 
            var colormarker = a[4]
            var typemarker = a[5]
            var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), 
                {icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({'marker-symbol':typemarker, 'marker-color': colormarker}),
                title: name
            });
            marker.bindPopup(title + '<br><a href=http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=>Navigate</a>');
            markers.addLayer(marker);
        }
```

I would like to merge the adresspoints (a[0],a[1]) with the link to google maps, so that the link guides the user directly to the navigation. But I don't know how to bring the data into the link.
Sorry for the silly beginner's question. But I have come so far now ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should take you to those lat/lng coordinates with a zoom of 16.

```
var url = 'https://maps.google.com/maps?q=' + a[0] + ',' + a[1] + '&z=16'

marker.bindPopup(title + '<br><a href=' + url + '>Navigate</a>');
```

[For example](https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=51.509946,-0.126944&z=16)